# CMSMS simpleform plugin "mail not sent" error

Tags: php, forms, plugins, cmsmadesimple

Help! I've just set up a page using the simpleform plugin for an easy email enquiry form.

[[url]http://bath-choral-society.org.uk/index.php?page=tickets-form[/url]](http://bath-choral-society.org.uk/index.php?page=tickets-form)

I've checked the stylesheet, the template, and the tags I've used (see below)

> {simpleform sendto='myemail@email.com' subject='Tickets Enquiry'}

I've changed the email that it's trying to send to, I've changed the subject, I've taken out the captcha bit that I was trying to use initially. Whatever I do, I still get the error message. What is going on??? Have I done something completely stupid?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

Can you receive a CMSMailer Test message?

Any errors reported in the Admin log or PHP Error log?

I haven't used that plugin before, but will test it if it helps.

Chris

Comment: Aargh! I really don't know what's going on, I didn't even set up this website initially. I've tried the CMSMailer test message, it appears to send, but then I don't receive anything. The error log in cPanel doesn't seem to show anything, don't know where to find the PHP error log?

Comment: Also... I didn't create the website initially, so I don't know if the CMSMailer settings are correct. As you might have guessed, I have no formal training, and I run the website in my spare time. I've looked for help from cPanel, and also from the web host, but I can't find anything about CMSMailer. 
The host is is webhosting UK, but the set up is cPanel. I think this is one of those times where using CMSMS is actually a disadvantage :(

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely to be that whoever set-up the site initially has not correctly set-up CMSMailer. You just need to put in the correct settings to be able to send emails. The smtp mail settings usually work fine, once all the correct settings and password are used.

The error log in cPanel is the right place to look - no errors is good news.